# A question about using the concavity of the logarithm in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization

Tags: inequality, logarithms, convex-analysis

From page 592 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/),

> Using concavity of the logarithm, we also have $$ \log(1 + 1/\sqrt{m}) \ge (\log 2)/\sqrt{m} \tag{1}$$

---

How can we make use of the concavity of the logarithm to get $(1)$? Actually, we can replace $1/\sqrt{m}$ with $x$ to simplify our notations and get
$$
\log(1 + x) \ge (\log 2)x
$$

This looks easy. I wasted a few hours on this problem, but failed to prove it.

---

In the original post I omitted the context in the book. Sorry about that. Specifically, $m$ denotes the number of inequalities which implies $0<1/\sqrt{m}\le 1$ and $0<x\le 1$. Now everything is clear.

Comment: Something is wrong here.  In the second version with $ x = 100 $, the LHS is much smaller than the RHS.  You get the same values in the first version with $ m = 0.0001 $.

Comment: As Siong Thye Goh says below, the inequality depends on $m \ge 1$, or $0 \le x \le 1$.  @RodrigodeAzevedo, it's in section 11.5.3, on p. 591 in the online edition.

Comment: @user2554330 $m$ denotes the number of inequalites which is positive integers. I improved the original question. Sorry about the previous ambiguity.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo In section 11.5.3, the mentioned inequality is just above $(11.29)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For concave function, we have $$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \ge \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda ) f(y)$$

Hence if $m \ge 1$,

\begin{align}
\log \left( 1+\frac1{\sqrt{m}}\right) &= \log \left( 1-\frac1{\sqrt{m}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}\right)\\
&=\log \left( \left(  1-\frac1{\sqrt{m}}\right)1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\right) 2\right)\\
&\ge \left(  1-\frac1{\sqrt{m}}\right)\log 1 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\right) \log 2\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\right) \log 2
\end{align}

Comment: Great!!! Neat!!!

Comment: But your $\lambda$ is not in $[0,1]$ for all $m$.  E.g. for $m=0.0001$ as in my comment above, $\lambda = -99$.

Comment: we need the assumption of $m \ge 1$. I agree with you that if $m<1$. it is not true. [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g1wt7cd2mp) is a graph.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh $m$ represents the number of inequalities in the book. Sorry about that. I already modified the original post.